# Android-уведомление на Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, qtcreator, уведомления

Здравствуйте! Пишу небольшое приложение на Qt для андроид. И интересно стало, как присылать пользователю уведомления? Например: "Уже 8 часов вечера, накормите питомца!"
И, заодно, как после того, как приложение закроют, оставить его в фоне?

Comment: Напишите логику в Qt , по ней дергайте метод в java через JNI, а дальше нативный дройд, создайте и покажите нотификацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с нативными функциями Android OS в Qt реализована через  Android Extras

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html. Что же это такое? Это C++ API, которое позволяет вызывать статические методы class файлов, которые вы можете написать сами и включить их в сам проект, по той же ссылке есть примеры использования нативных уведомлений http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html.
По поводу сервиса ничего конкретного сказать не могу, нагуглил лишь такую штуку http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidservices.html.
Так же могу посоветовать ссылочку https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-episode-7/.
Там очень подробно рассказывается про потоки.